# Handling call back in angular 2

Tags: angular, callback

I have a method to read data from link. I trying to access images that are width greater than 600 but  alert( this.images.length); this always give zero and this was executed before my call call back called

```
 readLink(url: string) {
this.isBusy = true;
this._http.get(`${this._helper.baseURL}/api/post/readlink?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`)
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    this.processResponse(data, url);
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  }
  );
 }
```

method to process the request data

```
 processResponse(result, url) {
if (result.images != null && result.images.length > 0) {
  result.images.forEach(el => {
    this.getMeta(el, function (res) {
      this.images.push(res);
      this.currentImage = this.images[0];
    });
  });
}
alert( this.images.length); // this always give zero and this was executed before my call bakc 
}
```

> this call back function to get valid images

```
getMeta(url, callback) {
const img = new Image();
img.src = url;
img.onload = function () {
  if (img.width > 260 && img.height > 150) {
    callback(url);
  }
};
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `this` inside the function, don't use `function () {`

```
this.getMeta(el, function (res) {
```

should be

```
this.getMeta(el, (res) => {
```

otherwise `this` will not point to the class instance where the function is defined.

See also
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer +1 for answering when we should not use function() . I have been confused and not clear for so many days :)

Comment: @PrithiviRaj glad to hear it is helpful to you as well :)